# knockout with mapping plugin, posting using postJSON with MVC, model collections always contain null objects

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got a model for my Page Creation:

```
public class PageCreateModel : ActionModel
{
    public IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> AvailablePermissions { get; set; }
    public IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> AvailableUsers { get; set; }
    public IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> AvailableGroups { get; set; }

    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public bool ShowHeading { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> RouteUrls { get; set; }
    public IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> SelectedEditingPermissions { get; set; }
    public IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> SelectedEditingUsers { get; set; }
    public IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>> SelectedEditingGroups { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using knockout mapping to convert this into a knockout model on page load:

```
 var mappedModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
```

Upon posting and using this code:

```
mappedModel.save = function(form) {
        mappedModel.AvailablePermissions([]);
        mappedModel.AvailableUsers([]);
        mappedModel.AvailableGroups([]);
        console.log(ko.toJS(mappedModel));
        ko.utils.postJson('@Url.Action("Create", "Page")', { pageCreateModel: ko.toJS(mappedModel) });
    };
```

It goes to this Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PageCreateModel pageCreateModel)
    {

        return View(HydrateModel(pageCreateModel));
    }
```

At this point my standard property values get posted find. But my collections (so far on my page I've only added `SelectedEditingUsers`) have empty objects in the collection. For instance if on the page I add 2 users to the collection, and I post it. The MVC model's SelectedEditingUsers will have a collection of two, but those objects contain an Empty Guid and null for the value.

Here is the data being sent to the server from Chrome console:

> pageCreateModel:{"AvailablePermissions":[],"AvailableUsers":[],"AvailableGroups":[],"Heading":"Test","ShowHeading":true,"Description":null,"RouteUrls":null,"SelectedEditingPermissions":[],"SelectedEditingUsers":[{"Key":"d81f409a-5fed-4330-8640-004bede4e6fb","Value":"User1"},{"Key":"5628ad64-567b-499d-bee1-cb6c3dc397eb","Value":"User2"}],"SelectedEditingGroups":[],"ActionSuccess":false,"ActionMessage":null,"**ko_mapping**":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"AvailablePermissions[0].Key":true,"AvailablePermissions[0].Value":true,"AvailablePermissions[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfe23.png).Key":true,"AvailablePermissions[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfe23.png).Value":true,"AvailablePermissions[2].Key":true,"AvailablePermissions[2].Value":true,"AvailablePermissions[3].Key":true,"AvailablePermissions[3].Value":true,"AvailablePermissions[4]...[etc]

How can I fix it so that the full model gets properly received by MVC? I need to use postJSON so I can use RedirectToAction and other similar things.

EDIT: Trying the AJAX call instead:

```
 mappedModel.save = function(form) {
        mappedModel.AvailablePermissions([]);
        mappedModel.AvailableUsers([]);
        mappedModel.AvailableGroups([]);
        //mappedModel.__ko_mapping__([]);
        //console.log(ko.toJS(mappedModel));
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Page")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.toJSON(mappedModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Success!");
            }
        });
        //ko.utils.postJson('@Url.Action("Create", "Page")', { pageCreateModel: ko.toJS(mappedModel) });
        //ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], { pageCreateModel: ko.toJS(mappedModel) });
        //ko.utils.postJson('@Url.Action("Test", "Page")', { ko.toJS(mappedModel) });

    };
```

And I still get the same problem:

[image]

And here is the POST from that:

> {"AvailablePermissions":[],"AvailableUsers":[],"AvailableGroups":[],"Heading":"Test","ShowHeading":true,"Description":null,"RouteUrls":null,"SelectedEditingPermissions":[],"SelectedEditingUsers":[{"Key":"5628ad64-567b-499d-bee1-cb6c3dc397eb","Value":"User1"},{"Key":"6d7439aa-7728-4add-953f-28b306fff5d0","Value":"User2"}],"SelectedEditingGroups":[],"SelectedViewingPermissions":[],"SelectedViewingUsers":[],"SelectedViewingGroups":[],"ActionSuccess":false,"ActionMessage":null,"**ko_mapping**":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"AvailablePermissions[0].Key":true,"AvailablePermissions[0].Value":true,"AvailablePermissions[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfe23.png).Key":true,"AvailablePermissions[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfe23.png).Value":true,"AvailablePermissions[2].Key":true,"AvailablePermissions[2].Value":true,"AvailablePermissions[3].Key":true,...etc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ko.utils.postJson` doesn't set the Content-Type request header to `application/json`. It will simply send the request as form encoded value. So use `$.ajax` instead which allows you to specify the correct content type header:

```
mappedModel.save = function(form) {
    mappedModel.AvailablePermissions([]);
    mappedModel.AvailableUsers([]);
    mappedModel.AvailableGroups([]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Page")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: ko.toJSON(mappedModel),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(data) {
           ...do something
        }
    });
};
```

The Content-Type request header is used by ASP.NET MVC when trying to read the request in order to know how is this request being serialized.

In addition to that you might want to replace the `IList<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>>` types with `IList<MyViewModel>` where `MyViewModel` would be a view model class exposing two public properties: `Key` and `Value`. I am not sure that the JSON serializer would cope well with those `KeyValuePair<Guid, string>` type.

Comment: But I don't understand why then the non-collection values get read fine? If MVC can't detect which serializer to use without content type set how could it even read the Heading and ShowHeading properties?  Since a JSON string is getting submitted. I wanted to use postJson so I could use RedirectToAction.

Comment: If you do not set the content type then the default model binder assumes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request. Except that when you use the `ko.toJSON(mappedModel)`, you are basically sending the JSON as a payload to the request and the model binder is incapable of understanding it. You may take a look at the [`following article`](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) to better understand the correct format that the default model binder expects in this case. Then use FireBug and compare your request to see that it simply doesn't conform to it.

Comment: So if you want to handle complex types with collections and so on you could either send them as a JSON object (but you should specify the correct Content-Type request header in this case) or conform to the wire format.

Comment: Well I tried your AJAX request answer and actually still had the same problem..I updated my question. Using a model generated from the mapping plugin shouldn't  be causing any issue right?

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the fact that you are using `KeyValuePair<Guid, string>`. I am not sure that the JSON serializer is handling those types properly. Try defining a view model and then replace your `SelectedEditingUsers` property type to `IList<MyViewModel>` where MyViewModel will have 2 public properties: `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: You are right. That was it, everything works fine now. Can you put that in your answer so it's easier to find

Comment: I have added this to the answer.